# Next.js build failed - function from next/script not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, cloudinary, next.js13

I'm building a CMS using next.js and one of the features is media management using Cloudinary. I've managed to include the Cloudinary Media Library widget with the use of next/script and it works perfectly in development but encountered an error and is refusing to build. I am using Next.JS with TypeScript

My Script component from next/script

```
 <Script
  id="cloudinary"
  defer
  src="https://media-library.cloudinary.com/global/all.js"
  onReady={function () {
    widgetRef.current = cloudinary.createMediaLibrary(
      {
        cloud_name: "<cloud name here>",
        api_key: "<api key here>",
        multiple: false,
      },
      {
        insertHandler: (data) => {
        const selectedImage = { ...data.assets[0] };
        form.setFieldValue("image", selectedImage.url);
        },
      }
    );

    setWidgetReady(true);

  }}></Script>
```

and later the widget is called by user interaction with a button

```
<Button
   onClick={() => widgetRef.current.show()}
   loading={!widgetReady}
   leftIcon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImage} />}
>
Select/Upload Image
</Button>
```

in dev, the widget opens with no issues

[Cloudinary Media Library Widget Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzTIN.png)

as I'm building for deployment here's the error

```
Type error: Cannot find name 'cloudinary'.

  207 |             src="https://media-library.cloudinary.com/global/all.js"
  208 |             onReady={function () {
> 209 |               widgetRef.current = cloudinary.createMediaLibrary(
      |                                   ^
  210 |                 {
  211 |                   cloud_name: "<cloud name here>",
  212 |                   api_key: "<api key here>",
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I'm not sure where to even begin debugging this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an initialization to Cloudinary:

```
        var cld = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({ cloud_name: 'my_cloud' });
        widgetRef.current = cld.createMediaLibrary(
                 {
                  cloud_name: "<cloud name here>",
                  api_key: "<api key here>",
                  .......
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it but unfortunately, I;m still gettin g the same error just on that line instead.

`Type error: Cannot find name 'cloudinary'.`

I think the best thing i can do for this is to rewrite this portion

Comment: Can you test adding ``` (window as any).cloudinary.createMediaLibrary(... ``` and let me know if you still receive the error?